# Jmeter wont write on CSV

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I've been scratching my head on this issue. It seems that Jmeter wont write on one of my empty CSV file and throws this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnN3U.png). But one of my CSV file in the same thread doesn't replicate the error and writes properly.

These is how I called my [CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3ZKk.png) and how [I printed it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsn3d.png).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything which could cause the error in your partial screenshot, if you need further assistance consider:

1. Adding [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) to visualize all your [variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which are being used in the script
2. Adding the full code **as text**, not as the screenshot so the issue could be reproduced.

Going forward it might be a better idea to use i.e. [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) instead of Groovy for writing the variables into the file as if you run your script with 2+ threads you might run into a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) with several threads concurrently writing into the file which most probably will result in data corruption/loss

Comment: I'll try and study your answer. I'll try to make a more comprehensive question next time I ask. Thank you!